# How to avoid defining two extra tables for an object that can have only 3 possible values and is part of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, activerecord

I tried to search this online but found this question quite difficult to formulate in a concise & intelligible way.

I am developing an application which enables users to choose from 3 types of authentications: Password, Finger Print & Face Recognition. Each user may opt for multiple types of these 3 and I need to store their picks in a relational database. So theoretically, there exists a many-to-many relationship between users and authentication_types.

I know this seems quite trivial and probably I am overanalysing things, but which would be the optimal way to model this at a relational database level? What I am trying to avoid but seems to be the only reasonable solution in a relational DB setting, is to create a table for login types (say LoginTypes) in which to store the 3 login types mentioned above and create an intermediary table for the many-to-many relationship (say UsersLoginTypes).

What's frustrating a little for me is that for only 3 types of login, I need to create one table to store them and another one for the many-to-many relationship. And any time I want to get the login types chosen by a user, I cannot simply select the user and extract the login types from the user's object, but I need to make a query that involves two another tables (LoginTypes & UsersLoginTypes). Do I miss a simpler solution here?

I thought of maybe assigning each login type a digit (eg. Password - 1, Fingerprint - 2, Face Recognition - 3) and have a field in the User's model for the login types, where to store a string containing the digits corresponding to what the user chose. And eventually, this is perhaps what I would go for if no better solution exists.

PS. I am using Ruby on Rails with ActiveRecord, if this changes something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1997, I once normalised a relational database model to death. It worked, was extremely flexible, but it invariably ground to a halt whenever you wanted to formulate an unforeseen query. It was already very tedious to formulate the query in the first place. (of course, that was at times when you always wrote your SQL manually - BI tools were a thing of the future).

So: a (master) table `users` , a (lookup) table `login_types` and a (child/intermediate) table `active_users_authentications` as your first shot is the correct way of modelling it relationally.

But if you want the system to be efficient/performant (and you don't need any further details for the authentication configurations - which you would store in `active_users_authentications`, of course), I for one would find it absolutely legitimate to have 3 Booleans (Yes/No) columns in the `users` table and call them: `has_pwd_auth`, `has_fgnpr_auth`, and `has_facerec_auth` .

Comment: Booleans I believe would be the best in my context as I do not need to store any other configurations. Thank you!